# How can I access a second disk drive from PHP?

Tags: php, linux, apache

I'm running Apache 2.4 and PHP 7 on CentOS 7. I run a web-based file server. The directory structure looks like this:

```
/var/www/example.com/public_html # Document Root
/var/www/file-transfer-center/   # Location of files for file server
```

Everything works great, but the partition that these files reside on is getting full. There is another partition on the machine:

```
lsblk
NAME            MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda               8:0    0 953.8G  0 disk
├─sda1            8:1    0   500M  0 part /boot
└─sda2            8:2    0 953.3G  0 part
  ├─centos-root 253:0    0    50G  0 lvm  /
  ├─centos-swap 253:1    0     4G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─centos-home 253:2    0 899.2G  0 lvm  /home
sdb               8:16   0   500G  0 disk
└─sdb1            8:17   0   500G  0 part
sdc               8:32   0  1000G  0 disk
└─sdc1            8:33   0  1000G  0 part
sr0              11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

And if I run `df -aTh | grep centos`:

```
/dev/mapper/centos-root xfs           50G   17G   34G  34% /
/dev/mapper/centos-home xfs          899G   34G  866G   4% /home
```

So it looks to me like I can just move my `file-transfer-center` directory to `/home` and I'll be all set.

I copied the files and changed the configuration of the path of my file transfer software to `/home/file-transfer-center`, but when I try to access the files, `php-fpm` gives me the error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught LogicException: The root path /home/file-transfer-center is not readable.

I checked the permissions and the `file-transfer-center` and all if it's contents are owned by `apache` and in the `wheel` group with 775 and 664 rights on directories and files, respectively.

I wrote a simple test:

```
var_dump(fopen('/home/file-transfer-center/fa498800-4102-46be-a7a6-3384f242a949', 'r'));
```

And it results in `false`. If I replace the path in that test with the original `file-transfer-center` path, it results in `resource(5) of type (stream)`.

I checked `open_basedir`, it is not set. Same with `user_dir`. I can't find anything that would indicate that the directory would be off limits to PHP.

What am I missing here? Am I correct in my analysis that `/home` is running on a separate logical partition of the same physical drive? Does that have something to do with it?

How can I explicitly tell PHP that it's cool to access `/home/file-transfer-center`?

**EDIT:** My web server is running as user `apache` and the `/home/file-transfer-center` directory is owned by `apache`:

```
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache wheel 60K Jan 11 17:12 file-transfer-center
```

Comment: Can you `su` the apache user and `cat` the file you tried opening in php? Can you post the exact permissions of `/home/file-transfer-center` (the directory itself)?

Comment: Apache is ran by a user, not your login user. It's either `www` or `www-data` or something simular. Just give that user or group access to that directory and you're done.

Comment: It's not PHP's job to care where and how the data is stored, managing partitions and disks is the file system's job. As long as the disk is mounted where it should and accessible with the correct permissions, PHP should be able to use it without issues.

Comment: @ccKep Yes, I can cat the files as user `apache`. Actual permissions: `drwxrwxr-x.  2 apache      wheel        60K Jan 11 17:12 file-transfer-center`. And yes, the Apache web server is running as user `apache`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your *nix file system doesn't care how many actual hard drives you have. All of the files are unified as a single file system.

You cannot just move files or your file-transfer-center directory into the /home directory. That directory, at least on my system, is owned by root:

```
$ ls -dal /home
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Apr 28  2016 /home
```

You would need sudo privileges in order to move any file or directory into the /home directory.

If you just moved the directory **file-transfer-center** from /var/www/file-transfer-center to /home/file-transfer-center, I would imagine this directory still has its same permissions.  However, if you created a new directory named /home/file-transfer-center and copied the contents and subdirectories into it, then it might be owned by root:root. I suggest you check the permissions on /home/file-transfer center with this command:

```
ls -dal /home/file-transfer-center
```

And see if apache has access to it.

You should also make sure that you are assigning the correct permissions for your web server. To find out which server the web server is, access this PHP script *via your webserver*:

```
<?
passthru("whoami");
```

it should output the name of the username of your web server. That user should have read and/or write access to the /home/file-transfer-center directory.

EDIT:
Looking more closely at the OP, I see there's a little period (.) at the end of the file permissions -- apparently this denotes a SELinux restriction. SELinux can [restrict apache access to home directories](https://www.unixmen.com/selinux-and-non-default-home-directory-locations/). Consider moving file-transfer-center directory back to /var/www/file-transfer-center -- can you mount the second drive there instead?

Comment: did you try the PHP script to spit out your apache username?

Comment: Just noticed the "." in your file permissions -- this apparently denotes extended file permissions info like an ACL. Been searching around a bit. Some suggestions like this: https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=1315

Comment: Having done a bit of reading about SELinux, I see that it often, as a security measure, denies apache access to /home directories. I've edited my answer to suggest that you mount the second drive so you can return your directory to /var/www

Comment: Holy cow I can't believe I forgot about SELinux. I'm sure that's it.